# how to remove square bracket in json formate string?

Tags: javascript, json

Remove the square bracket in this string.

```
{"id":[1],"latitude":[12.45787],"longitude":[11.77878]}
```

output:

```
{"id":1,"latitude":12.45787,"longitude":11.77878}
```

Comment: Parse the JSON into an object, iterate over each property of the object and assign the first element of the array to itself? Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Iterate over object properties, assign them the first item in their respective values.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str = '{"id":[1],"latitude":[12.45787],"longitude":[11.77878]}';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);

for (var key in obj) {
  obj[key] = obj[key][0];
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `RegExp` `/\[|\]/g`, `.replace()`

```
let res = `{"id":[1],"latitude":[12.45787],"longitude":[11.77878]}`.replace(/\[|\]/g, "");
```

Comment: It is not the proper way to handle for this solution. I think @4castle answer could be better than this answer. Because of this answer  will be threw an error if the array object having two values like `[11.77878,11.11111]`??

Comment: @RameshRajendran _"Because what about if the array having two values like `[11.77878,11.11111]`?"_ How would that change requirement  described at OP?

Comment: Am not asking about the OP requirement. am just thinking about the solution which is you has been given.

Comment: @RameshRajendran _"Am not asking about the OP requirement. am just thinking about the solution which is you has been given."_ Not sure what you mean? The Answer is a response in code to the requirement described at the Question.